# Overriding parent class variable with extended child variable

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to extend class which has a variable that I also need to be extended. Is there a "good" way of achieving this?

I have extended parent class and a variable that is in the parent class.
Now I need to use extended variable in child class. Here is pseudo-code:

```java
public class Parent {

    private ParentVariable variableToUse;
    //getters, setters
}

public class ParentVariable {
    //some fields
}

public class ChildVariable extends ParentVariable {
    //more fields
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    private ChildVariable variableToUse;
    //getters, setters
}
```

How should I override `"variableToUse"` so that every-time I try to access this variable from `"Child"` I would access `"ChildVariable"` instead of `"ParentVariable"`?

Comment: you are not overriding the variable, you are just hiding the original one, that's a great difference.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a type-safe way.

Comment: That looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you explain *why* you think you need to do this? What problem does it solve?

Comment: Parent class has some logic with variableToUse, which I need to keep as is, but in the Child class I need additional fields for variableToUse. So I don't want to change neither Parent class nor Parent variable, instead I need to extend those classes and so when accessing Child class variableToUse I would have those additional fields for variableToUse

Comment: You cannot override instance variables. As @Stultuske said you just hide it. The overriding is made at runtime based on the real object's type. Implement an overriden method that returns the variable you need.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "I need additional fields *for* variableToUse". Can you clarify it?

Comment: i.e. ParentVariable has variables name and surname, ChildVariable additionally has email

Comment: OK, I think I start to see what you want to do. If I am right then maybe this will help: `class Parent<T extends ParentVariable>{ T variableToUse; /*T should be also used in constructors, setters, getters*/ ..}` `class Child extends Parent<ChildVariable>{...}` this way `Child` *specifies* preferred type *for* `variableToUse` inherited from Parent class (it is still same variable declared in Parent class). Just remember that since in your example `variableToUse` is private in Child you would need to use setters/getters to access it.

Comment: So I assume there is no proper way of achieving this without altering Parent class code?

Comment: No, one of fundamental rules in Java is that "fields are not polymorphic", so overriding is reserved only for methods, never for fields.

Answer (score 0):

You will be effectively hiding the parent variable here by including "variableToUse" in the child class.

As variableToUse is of the type ParentVariable anyway, i suggest you leave it out of the ChildClass altogether, and use a getter which ensures type. 
Eg -

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    //private ChildVariable variableToUse; -> remove this

    private ChildVariable checkAndGetChildVariable() {
          if(variableToUse instanceof ChildVariable) {
                return (ChildVariable)variableToUse;
          }
          return null;//Or throw exception
    }
}
```

For further clarity, ensure this in the constructor

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    //private ChildVariable variableToUse; -> remove this
    public Child(ParentVariable variable) {
          super(checkChildVariable(variable));
    }

    private static ChildVariable checkChildVariable(ParentVariable variable) {
          if(variable instanceof ChildVariable) {
                return (ChildVariable)variable;
          }
          throw UnsupportedOperation("invalid type");
    }
}
```